# Remove string characters from a given found substring until the end in Python

Tags: python, string

I've got the following string: blah blah blah blah in Rostock

What's the pythonic way for removing all the string content from the word 'in' until the end, leaving the string like this: 'blah blah blah blah'

Comment: What have you tried that you consider un-pythonic?

Comment: Have you tried using regex?

Comment: @smassey, that should be an answer

Comment: And perhaps you should not use people's real names to protect their privacy

Comment: good idea @ThomasWeller

Comment: Actually the result will be `'blah blah blah blah '`. Note extra space at the end

Comment: @smac89: maybe that's not what he wants, so we need a trim()

Comment: @ThomasWeller, good point

Comment: @IanSpitz: please learn to write down all your requirements. As you can see, the question is unclear: How many of those strings do you have? Can "in" occur only in the end or are there other names like "Konstantin" that have "in" in their name. Do you want spaces to be stripped or not? Can there be other cities containing "in" like "Berlin"? IMHO, For a single name, it's not worth writing a program at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `split(" in ")`, you can split the string from the "in".

This produces a list with the two ends. Now take the first part by using [0]:

`string.split(" in ")[0]`

If you don't want the space character at the end, then use rstrip():
`string.split(" in ")[0].rstip()`

Welcome.

Comment: What if there's a `in` in the name like "Justin"?

Comment: @ThomasWeller, that was not part of the OP's requirements

Comment: Bear in mind cases like 'blah blah blinah in Rostock.' if you take this approach. At the very least, use `split(" in ")` rather than `split("in")`.

Comment: @ChrisLarson but I used the rstrip to remove spaces. But true point if the "in" is in the name. Lets hope not.

Comment: If OP would want to remove that part only on exactly that data, why would he write a program at all? He could just remove the unwanted part from the original data

Comment: @SurajKothari Your `rstrip` occurs _after_ the split. :)

Comment: @ThomasWeller To me the program seems like he wants the info before the location in the string. The location and name of a person is in the string so unlikely the "in" will be used as part of a normal sentence.

Comment: @ChrisLarson Isn't the rstrip meant to be at the end?

Comment: `s.split("in")[0].strip()` for right and left white space.

Comment: I edited the post to now having the split(" in ") :)

Comment: Also, I am assuming the main "in" is always included.

Comment: @SurajKothari I think you misunderstand my point. I'm suggesting they split on ' in ', rather than 'in', because ' in ' is less likely to occur in the the string they wish to preserve. Your rstrip is appropriate _after_ the split has occurred, which is how you placed it. But it doesn't affect the suggested split. I think we may be talking about to different things. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expression if the base unit is word.

```
import re
line = 'justin in Rostock'
print(re.split(r'\bin\b', line, maxsplit=1)[0].strip())
```

> justin

[example in regular expression](https://regex101.com/r/44H5wD/1)

Use [`str.partition`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=partition#str.partition) if the base unit is character.

```
line = 'blah blah blah blah in Rostock'
new_string = line.partition('in')[0].strip()

print(new_string)
```

> blah blah blah blah

`strip()` removes the space before `in`

Comment: Why split at the first occurrence and not the last?

Comment: `line = 'justin in Rostock'` will get partitioned as `just`

Comment: regex is used to split by words

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether you call it pythonic or not. At least it seems to do the job.

```
def getNameAndCity(nameWithCity: str) -> (str, str):
    if not " in " in nameWithCity:
        return nameWithCity, None
    pieces = nameWithCity.split(" in ")
    name = " in ".join(pieces[0:-1])
    return name, pieces[-1]

# No 'in' at all
assert ("Michael",None) == getNameAndCity("Michael")
# Nothing special
assert ("Johan", "Oslo") == getNameAndCity("Johan in Oslo")
# "'in' in City
assert ("Sandra", "Berlin") == getNameAndCity("Sandra in Berlin")
# 'in' in Name and City
assert ("Christine", "Berlin") == getNameAndCity("Christine in Berlin")
# 'in' as an extra token
assert ("Christine in Love", "Berlin") == getNameAndCity("Christine in Love in Berlin")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "Ahe, Christiane Dr. von der Praxis für Kieferorthopädie in Rostock"
if " in " in s:
    s = s[:s.find(" in ")]
# Else leave the string untouched.
```

Comment: Almost. This will skip the last character in the string if the thing you are finding does not exist

Comment: @smac89 Why would you make such a special case?

Comment: Because special cases are the only ones that matter

Comment: `index = s.find('in'); s = s[:index] if index > 0 else s`

Comment: if it's harder to read, then don't use it. I was just suggesting a different approach